# Conditional probability inequality proof

Tags: probability, inequality

There are two index sets $I= \{1, 2, \dots, m\}$ and $J = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Then, I have independent random variables $X_{ij}, \forall i \in I, j \in J$. Fix $i \in I$; then we have $X_{ij}$ is identical for all $j \in J$.

Fix $k \in J$, I am wondering if I could have the following probability inequality$$ P\left(X_{1k} \leq Y, X_{2k} \leq Y \mid Y = \max_{I\in I} \min_{j \in J} X_{ij}\right) \leq $$
$$
P\left(X_{1k} \leq Y \mid Y = \max_{I\in I} \min_{j \in J} X_{ij}\right) \cdot P\left( X_{2k} \leq Y \mid Y = \max_{I\in I} \min_{j \in J} X_{ij}\right)$$

If the inequality holds, how to show it? If the inequality does not hold, can we have some inequality of a similar format? Thank you very much!

Comment: If the $X_{ij}$'s are identical for all $j$, then why not just call it $X_i$, then see how things simplify?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We cannot simplify like that because we need to focus on a specific $j$, i.e., the k, in the inequality.